# Checking if two layers of features exists on same location using QGIS Python?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis

I have two layers named Layer1 and Layer2 containing some features. Layer2 features are overlapped on Layer1 features.

Using python I want to check if a feature exists on layer2 when i select a feature in layer1. Is there any method to do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a confirmation, this code will tell you. If you want to do further things, here you have the base to start with. You haven't mentioned the size of your layers. You might encounter some performance issues for big files.

```
from shapely.geometry import shape, MultiPolygon
import fiona


layer1 = fiona.open('layer1.shp')
layer2 = fiona.open('layer2.shp')
multi_polygon = MultiPolygon([shape(feat['geometry']) for feat in layer2])

for feature in layer1:
    geometry1 = shape(feature['geometry'])
    if geometry1.intersects(multi_polygon):
        print('Feature {} intersects layer 2'.format(feature))
```

Comment: Thanks for your help , but its not working in my plugin.I have line features in my layer so is there any changes to make in that code

Comment: Then change MultiPolygon for MultiLineString

Comment: above code you used **feat['geometry']** in this geometry refers to field of layer right ?